# Does SQLite favour keeping indexes in its cache when possible?

Tags: memory-management, sqlite, indexing

I'm working in a memory constrained environment with SQLite 3.

I'll be setting the PRAGMA cache size to be (say) 1MB.

Assume I have 2MB of data, and 100Kb of index data.

Will SQLite attempt to keep the indexes in its memory cache over and above the data itself (leaving 900Kb of data in cache)?

If not, how are the indexes accessed from a memory perspective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, Indexes will not be held indefinitely in memory cache.** If new data will be inserted, updated or deleted, sqlite3 may simply free less used data.

In fact, indexes do have very little in common with memory management: With every `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, sqlite3 will rearrange the data (depending on your system either on your HD or RAM). Simplified you may say, that the table is already ordered, when you are trying to access it. Compared to tables without indexes, there is not more memory needed.